# How to get wordpress users avartars from database manually

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I want to list my users which are in wordpress according to their roles with json api.

Normally I use v2 api.
**x.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?page=1&per_page=100**

api doesn't return me user roles or I couldn't filter it. Like author or subscriber.

I wanted to write a different php file myself, where I can take the roles and read them, but the shortcoming here is that the user avatar does not come.

Here my custom php kodu.

```
$sql =  "SELECT u.id,u.display_name,um.meta_value  FROM wpuy_usermeta um inner JOIN wpuy_users u on u.ID = um.user_id WHERE meta_key = 'wpuy_capabilities' Order by u.display_name asc";


$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  print json_encode($rows);

} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

all I need is id user name, user role, user avatar. how can i solve this

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema) is capable of giving you users roles.

However, in order to access this information, you need to declare the "`context`" structure as "`edit`".

#### Example Request URL

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/users?page=1&per_page=100&context=edit
```

Here is the result of my own query with Postman in the image below.

[image]

But the result of doing this query directly will cause unauthorized access with `401 status code`.

For this, you must verify your identity on the REST API or have successfully passed the authorization process with the new feature.

> See also: [WordPress Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), [WordPress Application Passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

Finally, the `/users/` query already gives you the Avatar URLs.

[image]

Comment: I see this before but couldn't figure out the error "code": "rest_forbidden_context",. I will try again. Thank you.